# nginx: proxy special file patterns (css) from s3

Tags: nginx

we are serving a web app with nginx. It proxys everything that comes in over https to a server listening on localhost.

Now I want nginx to act as a proxy and serve our css files from s3.

As I want to serve different files based on the hostname the file is queried on (while always serving the same html content) it is not possible to serve files directly from s3

What's the best practise in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is not route traffic to S3 through your server, which will only serve to slow it down. You can load assets from S3 over SSL using a URL structure like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket-name/example.jpg

It's also advised to serve your static content from a separate domain, as browsers open up a limited number of parallel connections to a given domain.

Another reason to serve your static content off a separate domain is to improve performance by the domain being "cookie-less". Your app likely uses cookies, and the browser is setting an cookie header to it on every request. That wouldn't be the case on the S3 domain, which doesn't set a cookie.

Using alternate domains for CDNs is common. People tend not to notice because the URLs don't appear in the Location bar, only in the source code.

Comment: not possible in my case, see my changes. I want to proxy requests to something.domain.com/style.css to s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/something.domain.com/style.css

Comment: I think you could use `proxy_pass https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/$host/style.css` but I would recommend modifying the HTML for each host to connect directly to S3 for the reasons above.

Comment: as our framework (meteor) serves the css itself and its core is not that easy hackable this is not really an option.

Comment: I believe you have the option to edit the HTML Meteor serves in  `client/body.html` and link to a CSS file if your choice, ignoring or disabling the CSS handling that's built in.

Comment: As we want the css handling during development that is not that easy. We would need to remove the css during build. At least there is now not much more load on the nginx server as it was serving the app all the time complete with css, now the css comes from s3 and is cached by nginx. The only reason i've choosen s3 is that we have multiple servers all serving the same app and we didn't want to upload all css to all servers.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using this block. The problem was that I didn't use a resolver.

```
 location ~ \.css {
                # Important to resolve host of s3
                resolver 8.8.8.8;
                # we can only ever GET/HEAD these resources
                limit_except GET {
                        deny all;
                }

                # cookies are useless on these static, public resources
                proxy_ignore_headers set-cookie;
                proxy_hide_header set-cookie;
                proxy_set_header cookie "";

                proxy_hide_header x-amz-delete-marker;
                proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
                proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
                proxy_hide_header x-amz-version-id;

                # only rely on last-modified (which will never change)
                proxy_hide_header etag;

                # heavily cache results locally
                proxy_cache_valid 200 28d;
                proxy_cache_valid 403 24h;
                proxy_cache_valid 404 24h;

                # s3 replies with 403 if an object is inaccessible; essentially not found
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                error_page 403 =404 /_error/http-404.html;

                # go get it from s3
                proxy_pass https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/$host/style.css;

                # annotate response about when it was originally retrieved
                add_header x-cache '$upstream_cache_status $upstream_http_date';

                # heavily cache results downstream
                expires max;
        }
```